# Using sapply within lapply only on certain variables/nested loop

Tags: r, nested-loops, lapply, sapply

I would like to adress my question in two steps in order for me to understand the way of coding better.

**Part 1:**

Suppose I have a list like this:

```
x <- data.frame(replicate(5,sample(0:100,10,rep=TRUE)))

y <- data.frame(replicate(5,sample(0:100,10,rep=TRUE)))

z <- list(x, y)
```

I would like to get the range of numbers of each column of each list.
I did not really understand how I can combine lapply with sapply to get results for each column of the dataframes within my list. Any ideas on how I could do this?

All I could get to run properly is if I wanted to get the range of let's say the third column of the first list element:

```
range(z[[1]][[2]])
```

**Part 2:**

The second part of my question goes a bit further. This time I will add a column with characters to my dataframes.

```
a <- data.frame(replicate(5,sample(0:100,10,rep=TRUE)))
a$x6 <- letters[1:10]

b <- data.frame(replicate(5,sample(0:100,10,rep=TRUE)))
b$x6 <- letters[1:10] 

c <- list(x, y)
```

I would like to get the range of numbers of each column of each list except for column 6 which is not numeric. I do not want to delete this column but would rather only query the numeric columns.

Any ideas on how I could do this efficiently? I presume a combination of lapply and sapply would be the best.

If you have an idea on how to do this with a nested loop, that would also be interesting to know. Maybe the second part also only works with a nested loop...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first can be done with

```
lapply(z, function(a) sapply(a,range))

[[1]]
     X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
[1,]  2 13 28  2  3
[2,] 95 97 98 99 85

[[2]]
     X1 X2 X3 X4  X5
[1,]  7  4 16  5  19
[2,] 90 90 82 84 100
```

The second can be done with

```
lapply(c, function(a) sapply(a[sapply(a,is.numeric)],range))

[[1]]
     X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
[1,]  7  5  0  3  8
[2,] 97 81 96 93 94

[[2]]
     X1 X2  X3 X4 X5
[1,]  8  4   0  9  7
[2,] 72 90 100 99 94
```

The internal `sapply` in this one creates a logical vector of the column indices of each element of `c` that are numeric, so it will keep the character column out of the loop.

By the way, it is a bad idea to use `c` as a variable name in R, as it is also a common function!

Comment: Thanks a lot, also for the explanations! This worked very well for me! :-)

Answer (score 0):

The first one is straightforward using nested functions.

```
lapply(z, function(d) { sapply(d, range) })
[[1]]
     X1 X2 X3 X4  X5
[1,]  7  0  1  0   1
[2,] 86 82 96 91 100

[[2]]
     X1 X2 X3 X4 X5
[1,]  6  0  3 14  1
[2,] 98 84 99 89 73
```

For the second, the nested functions start getting a little ugly:

```
> lapply(z, function(d) {
   sapply(d, function(col) {
    if (is.numeric(col)) { range(col) } else { c(NA, NA) }
   })
  })
[[1]]
     X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 x6
[1,]  8  0  3 12  0 NA
[2,] 93 97 92 97 97 NA

[[2]]
     X1  X2 X3 X4 X5 x6
[1,] 20  31 10  5 17 NA
[2,] 84 100 88 94 99 NA
```